# What is the best way to calculate mode on mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, workbench

On workbench I noticed there is no mode function and I'm struggling to find a way to calculate. I've seen some examples where they use nested queries with count() and max(), but that doesn't appear to be working. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT max(mode_age) FROM ( 
SELECT count(age) AS mode_age 
FROM new_schema.`divvy_trips_2013` WHERE usertype = 'Subscriber' AND age <> '2013') AS s
```

but I just get the total row count in the end. when I flip it (count nested max) I get 1.

Comment: what is  a mode function?

Comment: trying to find the value that appears most frequently in a data set

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple example of how you could calculate the mode of a column in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE mode_test(value INT);

INSERT INTO mode_test VALUES (1),(2),(4),(4),(4),(5),(6),(7);

SELECT value as mode
FROM mode_test
GROUP BY value
ORDER BY count(value) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Sample output

| mode |
| --- |
| 4 |

Answer (score 0):

You need always `GROUP BY age`

```
SELECT 
    age,
    mode_age
FROM
    (SELECT 
        age,
        COUNT(age) AS mode_age
    FROM
        new_schema.divvy_trips_2013
    WHERE
        usertype = 'Subscriber'
        AND age <> '2013'
GROUP BY age) AS s
ORDER BY mode_age DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But simpler is

```
SELECT
    age ,
    COUNT(age) AS mode_age
FROM
    new_schema.divvy_trips_2013
WHERE
    usertype = 'Subscriber'
        AND age <> '2013'
GROUP BY age
ORDER BY mode_age DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It appears to me that your queries are returning the maximum number of occurrences, rather than the **value** which occurs most frequently.